# Backup outlook e-mail to the cloud and be able to search mails online

Tags: backup, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

Is there a way to backup my old e-mails to the cloud while still being able to search and view them online.

Comment: There are many ways: from uploading your email to any webmail (like Hotmail or Gmail) to purchasing Office 365. What are your requirements (in addition to search)?

Comment: I just want to be able to search them for reference and not to take up space on my local computer

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend you create a [Windows Live Hotmail](http://mail.live.com), connect it to your Outlook. This way you will be able to simply drag-and-drop or copy-and-paste your Outlook items into this account. Outlook automatically synchronizes all folders using [Outlook Hotmail Connector](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=24677) (Outlook 2010 will install it automatically after your add the account).

You will be able to search and a great deal more. Hotmail have Outlook-style inteface, folders, calendars and contacts. Give it a try, you will not be dissapointed!

Answer (score 0):

Just like thims said you could try [office 365 exchange online](http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/office365/exchange-online.aspx). And pst is microsoft propriety so gmail and other webmail services wont open them.But if you make a .dbx or a .wab file from outlook express you can uplocad it to live mail to go through it .

If you are always going to have access to outlook you can always put your .pst files on cloud data servers like [dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/home) an just point your outlook to the .dropbox folder with pst in it.

Comment: No need to add PST to anywhere. Moreover, this is a very bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can import in to gmail and just search through gmail.

Instructions here: http://www.keenerliving.com/importing-outlook-into-gmail